# Oracle to PostgreSQL migration with ogr2ogr only imports first geoloc column

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial, migration

I transfer Oracle tables to PostGIS using Oracle Wallet and

```
 ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=<host> port=5432 user=<user> dbname=<dbname> password=<pwd>" OCI:<USERNAME>/<PASSWORD>@<SID>:<table>
```

It transfers all regular columns and the first geoloc column. Tables with multiple geoloc columns are not transferred correctly. I can create pg tables with multiple geoloc columns by joining several tables within Pg client.

Is there a way to copy multiple geoloc columns with ogr2ogr?

Comment: Do you have all geoloc columns registered in ALL_SDO_GEOM_METADATA?